# Remote Desktop Client broken The system cannot find the file specified mstsc.exe.mui

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm facing this issue on a PC running Windows 7 Professional SP1 x64, updated to the latest (Oct 17) Security and Quality rollup.

It's impossible, as any user, to run `mstsc.exe`. The error states:

`mstsc.exe`

`The system cannot find the file specified.`

`c:\Windows\System32\<LANG_NAME>\mstsc.exe.MUI`.

[image: mstsc_error]

The event viewer's showing no messages at all about this. I've look into all sections and for any type of event, not just errors and warnings.

I've been googling for the error and found [numerous posts](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22C%3A%5Cwindows%5Csystem32%5C%3Clang_name%3E%5Cmstsc.exe.mui%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=cTXnWY3WO9Kv8we4t4KQBg) related to the problem, but none of the soultions worked for me.

I'll briefly explain the steps I took in order to try to fix this:

- compared `mstsc.exe` and `mstsc.exe.mui`'s locations with a known good system.
- copied both files from the known good system in the broken one
- as the default mui location for 32 bit executables on this system is `C:\Windows\System32\it-IT\` I created another folder in it named `it` and put inside it `mstsc.exe.mui aaclient.dll.mui mstscax.dll.mui`. I also copied this new `it` folder in `C:\Windows\System32\`. So now I have three copies of this three files in `C:\Windows\System32\it-IT\` `C:\Windows\System32\it` and `C:\Windows\System32\it-IT\it`
- I've search into the registry for the word `mstsc.exe.mui` and found just two keys, non related to this file's path. 
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMPONENTS\DerivedData\Components\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..cesclient.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_it-it_5f6e83504ee8d5f5` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMPONENTS\DerivedData\Components\amd64_microsoft-windows-t..cesclient.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18540_it-it_5f49fb9c4f04de0d`.
- Then I've found a working and updated PC running Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64 English, and took `mstsc.exe.mui aaclient.dll.mui mstscax.dll.mui` from its 
  `C:\Windows\System32\en-US`. I've put it in `en-US` `en` and `en-US\en`
- I tought I might have installed an english version of the `mstsc.exe` that might want to find english dlls in the italian path, so I tried to overwrite italian's files with english files. I also tried the other way around, with files from the italian system in the english's folders.
- I've found that installing `KB2574819-v2-x64` might fix this, it was already installed on this system so I tried to remove it and reinstall it back.
- I wasn't able to find a way to remove and reinstall mstsc application/feature.
- I tried disabling antivirus protection.
- I've scanned the machine for rootkits and virus, with no luck at all. It's always been protected with a commercial antivirus solution that never expired since it's been in production, and it's always been used by a conscious person, and WITHOUT administrative rights.
- I've performed a full `chkdsk` pre boot.
- I've scanned with `sfc /scannow` and it found no corrupted system files.

**I tried all this steps, with no luck at all but I think I might have still missed something, and don't want to wipe and reinstall a system that is performing perfectly but this issue. Anybody's got any clues?**

Another detail that might be important, I don't think the `mstsc.exe` was ever run since this PC is in production. Just in the last few weeks they introduced new features that bring on this PC the need to use the rdp client. As far as I know the problem might be present since the fresh installation. As this system was installed in 2014 and is always been up to date, I suspect it might be a problem with the install image, or with the updates that went through years till now. Unfortunately I can't determine when the problem with `mstsc.exe` started. This PC is an AD member and has always received updates from their WSUS. It's never been unpatched or without business antivirus solution since 2014.

---

**Relevant edit: as supposed in the answer, yes, it was an english system and the italian language pack was installed before PC went in production.**

Comment: Is this behavior the same on every user on the system?

Comment: Yes, as the question states: “it’s impossible, as any user,...” I tried even a domain admin and a local admin account. It’s a client issue.

Comment: must be because the OS can't figure out what LANG_NAME is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you changed the language on the computer when the problem started?

Here are some possible remedies :

1. Try to reinstall
   [RDP 8.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2592687/remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-8-0-update-for-windows-7-and-windows-serve)
   or
   [RDP 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2923545/update-for-rdp-8-1-is-available-for-windows-7-sp1),
   as the case may be.
2. The file you might be missing might really be `C:\Windows\system32\wbem\<LANG_NAME>\mstsc.mfl`.
3. Try the [Windows Update Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4027322/windows-windows-update-troubleshooter)
4. It is possible that although your computer is Italian, `mstc.exe`
   is English. Try to create a subfolder `en-US` and copy there
   the files as follows:

   ```
   c:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe
   c:\windows\system32\mstscax.dll
   C:\Windows\System32\aaclient.dll
   c:\windows\system32\en-US\mstsc.exe.mui
   c:\windows\system32\en-US\mstscax.dll.mui
   ```

Note also that as your Windows is 64-bits, and if you are also using a
64-bit Explorer, these files should actually reside in
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Comment: Indeed! I didn't knew how too reinstall RDP as mentioned in the OP. Following your suggestion I fixed at point 1); reinstalling KB2592687 for the italian language did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in Windows 11, I think resulting from Windows Update on 15 Feb 2024 (although I had not updated in a while). It did not exist on my hard drive (after 5 minute search using windows - a lot of rubbish in windows update but they never bother to fix the disk search speed). I had to get the file from another computer. To copy it was tricky, Windows kept saying `Access Denied` even as administrator. I found I had to copy it using this (using cmd runas admin):

```
xcopy c:\dev\mstsc.exe.mui C:\Windows\System32\en-US /h /o
```

That fixed my Remote Desktop.